# How to Get Variable to Work Inside and Out of Function

Tags: python

I am trying to make simple unweighted gpa calculator and I have run into a problem.  I cannot get the values created inside of my function out of it to do the final calculation.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ("Welcome to the un-weighted gpa calculator!")

year_one_gpa = ' '

def year_one():
    number_classes = input("How many classes did you take your first year in highschool?(Please enter an integer, no percents): ")

    class_gpa = [ ]

    global year_one_gpa

    for i in range(1, number_classes + 1):
        grade = input("What was your final grade in the class: " )

        if grade >= 93 and grade <= 100:
            class_gpa.append(4.0)

        elif grade >= 90 and grade <= 92:
            class_gpa.append(3.7)

        elif grade >= 88 and grade <= 89:
            class_gpa.append(3.3)

        elif grade >= 83 and grade <= 87:
            class_gpa.append(3.0)

        elif grade >= 80 and grade <= 83:
            class_gpa.append(2.7)

        elif grade >= 78 and grade <= 79:
            class_gpa.append(2.3)

        elif grade >= 73 and grade <= 77:
            class_gpa.append(2.0)

        elif grade >= 70 and grade <= 72:
            class_gpa.append(1.7)

        elif grade >= 68 and grade <= 69:
            class_gpa.append(1.3)

        elif grade >= 65 and grade <= 67:
            class_gpa.append(1.0)

        else:
            class_gpa.append(0.0)



    return class_gpa

    year_one_gpa = (sum(class_gpa)/ float(len(class_gpa)))



year_one()

print year_one_gpa
```

That is what I have so far and whenever it prints the year_one_gpa, a blank list comes up.

Comment: Try moving your `return` statement to the end of the function block (i.e. just after the `year_one_gpa = ...` line)

Answer (score 1):

When you use `return` you step outside the function.

Try replacing this :

```
return class_gpa

year_one_gpa = (sum(class_gpa)/ float(len(class_gpa)))
```

by this :

```
year_one_gpa = (sum(class_gpa)/ float(len(class_gpa)))
return class_gpa
```

Comment: Whenever I did that the list came up empty again :(

Comment: That's because you don't save the value that is returned, and because you are abusing global variables instead of doing things how they should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you are writing an if/else statement with more than 4-5 cases then you are doing something very inefficiently. There is always a better way than a giant elif string.

For example you could use a dictionary and map values or you could use a list of tuples for the minimum for a grade.

like so:

```
gradeToGpa = [ (93, 4.0) , (90, 3.7), (88, 3.3) ..... ]
```

you can then restate the logic as:

```
for score, gpa in gradeToGpa:
    if score < classGrade:
        classGPA = gpa
        break
```

second, you should not use **range(1, number+1)** you should instead use range(0,number) or, even better, **range(number)** which assumes a 0 at front.

You are using the `global` term very incorrectly, instead in python you should be returning a tuple from the function.

Also, you have a return statement in your function followed by code. As the return statement will always execute any code after it is not relevant.

```
return class_gpa   #leave the function here

year_one_gpa = (sum(class_gpa)/ float(len(class_gpa)))  # this will never run
```

Instead you should write this:

```
year_one_gpa = (sum(class_gpa)/ float(len(class_gpa)))

return year_one_gpa
```

and, outside of the function you should write:

```
my_gpa = year_one()

print my_gpa
```

Lastly, stackoverflow is not a place to have people debug your code. It is grossly apparent that you did not do a proper amount of reading before coming here to have someone solve your problems for you. I recommend picking up a book on python or reading some tutorials. Return statements are absolutely fundamental to all programming.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a couple of mistakes here firstly a global variable is declared outside the function and local variables can only be accessed inside the function so the modified code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ("Welcome to the un-weighted gpa calculator!")

year_one_gpa = ' '

def year_one():
    number_classes = input("How many classes did you take your first year in highschool?(Please enter an integer, no percents): ")

    class_gpa = [ ]

    global year_one_gpa

    for i in range(1, number_classes + 1):
        grade = input("What was your final grade in the class: " )

        if grade >= 93 and grade <= 100:
            class_gpa.append(4.0)

        elif grade >= 90 and grade <= 92:
            class_gpa.append(3.7)

        elif grade >= 88 and grade <= 89:
            class_gpa.append(3.3)

        elif grade >= 83 and grade <= 87:
            class_gpa.append(3.0)

        elif grade >= 80 and grade <= 83:
            class_gpa.append(2.7)

        elif grade >= 78 and grade <= 79:
            class_gpa.append(2.3)

        elif grade >= 73 and grade <= 77:
            class_gpa.append(2.0)

        elif grade >= 70 and grade <= 72:
            class_gpa.append(1.7)

        elif grade >= 68 and grade <= 69:
            class_gpa.append(1.3)

        elif grade >= 65 and grade <= 67:
            class_gpa.append(1.0)

        else:
            class_gpa.append(0.0)


    year_one_gpa = (sum(class_gpa)/ float(len(class_gpa)))

    return class_gpa




year_one()

print year_one_gpa
```

Also you might want to save value returned by year_one in a variable I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `year_one_variable = None` on the first line of your code!